# How can I override the default template used by a page or article in pelican?

Tags: python, pelican

I would like to know how can I use a different template for a page or article in pelican?

So far, it seems that for articles is using `article.html` and for pages `page.html`.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the output filename by using the `Template` metadata in your individual files. This will override the default that you set in your configuration file.

For Markdown you would include this in your header:

```
 Template: template_name
```

This is [discussed in the FAQ](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-assign-custom-templates-on-a-per-page-basis) on the pelican website.

Answer (score 1):

Pelican looks for templates in whatever directory you've specified as `THEME` in your `pelicanconf.py`. If you just want to change what the output looks like, you can modify `article.html` or `page.html` in that directory (the default is `themes/notmyidea` relative to wherever pelican is installed). See [how to create themes for Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/themes.html) for more.

If you actually want to change the name of the file that Pelican looks for to generate the articles or pages, that's a bit trickier. I don't know of any setting that allows this to be altered, but the relevant bit of the Pelican source appears to be [here](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/contents.py#L297), so if you really want this you could consider subclassing `Content` yourself of just changing the relevant lines in your copy of Pelican.